# Asp.NET MVC Radiobutton not working from HttpPost in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I choose true or false but always I saw false default value of bool. Please help me.

**MODEL**

```
public partial class Istek
{
   public bool iade { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

I tried this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.iade, "true", new { @id = "iade-evet", @class = "md-radiobtn" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.iade, "false", new { @id = "iade-hayir", @class = "md-radiobtn" })
```

and this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.iade, true, new { @id = "iade-evet", @class = "md-radiobtn" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.iade, false, new { @id = "iade-hayir", @class = "md-radiobtn" })
```

and this

```
<input type="radio" id="iade-evet" name="iade" class="md-radiobtn">
<input type="radio" id="iade-hayir" name="iade" class="md-radiobtn">
```

but all of these not worked.

**CONTROLLER**

[image]

Comment: Both your first 2 snippets work perfectly fine. And if its not working for you have not given all the relevant information.

Comment: I said "all of these not worked from HttpPost". I fix my code with Jasen. Thanks again Jasen :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is mostly correct but not broken. It's not necessary to escape the `id`. `class` is marked because it is a C# reserved keyword.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.iade, true, new { id = "iade-evet", @class = "md-radiobtn" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.iade, false, new { id = "iade-hayir", @class = "md-radiobtn" })
```

Now check the rendered HTML

```
<input id="iade-evet" name="iade" value="True" ... />
<input id="iade-hyir" name="iade" value="False" ... />
```

The `name` should match the model's property name. If you have a multi-part identifier like `x.iade` (this often happens when you reference a child model) then you'll need to change the parameter names so they match.

Either the action signature

```
public ActionResult Ekle(Istek x, bool zararliEtki)
{
}
```

Or the model's identifier in the view

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => istek.iade, true, new { id="iade-evet", @class="md-radiobtn" })
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed like this and its work :)

@Html.RadioButton("istek.iade", true, new { id="iade-evet", @class="md-radiobtn" })

Answer (score 0):

Add value to radio button. Its not a checkbox which automatically sends true or false. radio button must have a value.